# How to draw a 2D cross-section of a 3D object?

Tags: unity

I am creating a game where I only want the user to see the 2D intersection of a plane with a 3D object. The goal of the game is to move this plane to a certain position and rotation, which gives a certain 2D shape. [Here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CrossSectionsOfRegularPolyhedra/) is a link to a website which illustrates the 2D slices of a 3D object.
How do I approach this if I only want the player to see the slice.

Just to be clear, the solution does not necessarily have to be in 3D, since the ui for the player is going to be 2D anyway

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is with a 2-pass custom shader. You can see it visualized here in purple (the grey ghost material is a separate effect I've drawn to help visualize the mesh shape we're cutting):

[image]

We'll give our shader a 4-vector representing our cross-section plane. The first 3 components will be the (unit) plane normal, and the fourth will be the distance of the plane from the origin.

We'll draw our shape in two passes, using the plane vector to cut away the part of the mesh between the cross section plane and the camera.

- In the first pass, we draw only front-facing triangles, and we draw them only to the depth buffer, leaving our scene colour unchanged.
- In the second pass, we draw only back-facing triangles (the inside of the mesh).

  These will be blocked from drawing anywhere the front-facing triangles already drew to the depth buffer, except for the hole we cut with our cross-section plane. So the net effect is we'll see only the cross section drawn in the scene. :)

Here's a shader that does this (I repeat basically the same code in both passes, so you could make this a bit neater by putting the shared code in a `.cginc` include file and just referencing it):

```
Shader "Unlit/CrossSection"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        _Section("Section Plane", Vector) = (0, 1, 0, 0)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Transparent"}
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CULL Back
            Blend Zero One

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float sectionDepth : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            float4 _Section;

            v2f vert (float4 vertex : POSITION)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(vertex);

                float3 worldPosition = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, vertex).xyz;
                float cameraSide = sign(_Section.w - dot(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, _Section.xyz));
                o.sectionDepth = cameraSide * (dot(worldPosition, _Section.xyz) - _Section.w);

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                clip(i.sectionDepth);
                return 0;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            CULL Front

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float sectionDepth : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;
            float4 _Section;

            v2f vert(float4 vertex : POSITION)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(vertex);

                float3 worldPosition = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, vertex).xyz;
                float cameraSide = sign(_Section.w - dot(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, _Section.xyz));
                o.sectionDepth = cameraSide * (dot(worldPosition, _Section.xyz) - _Section.w);

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                clip(i.sectionDepth);
                return _Color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'll have to adjust my idea slightly, but I think it'll work now.