# How do I use shader to draw only outline of a cross section in unity?

Tags: unity, shaders

[How to draw a 2D cross-section of a 3D object?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/181906/how-to-draw-a-2d-cross-section-of-a-3d-object)
I used the shader from the answer and it works great, but I am wondering how do I draw only the outline of the cross-section(as opposite to the whole plane)?
I am a beginner in shaders so I would really like some help. Can I first detect if the vertex is on the plane in vertex shader and then pass that info to pixel shader? How can I achieve that?